# What happens if you are late with your payments to an Islamic bank?

Tags: banking

According to one answer here: https://www.quora.com/How-do-Islamic-banks-make-money-if-they-cant-charge-interest-because-of-sharia, you have to pay what you owe and the bank can force you to pay.

So what happens if you have to delay your payment or are unable to pay anymore?

Edit:

Ok, I can not comment, so to clarify: if I can not pay, how would the bank usually force me to pay? Is the amount of money I have to pay increased by some fine? Is my property sold off?

Comment: In the light of "you have to pay what you owe and the bank can force you to pay," what exactly is the question?

Comment: You only pay what you own. No interest. You will have to check this with the bank itself though as each bank differs.